# How can I override a function of type member in Scala?

Tags: scala

Suppose I have a code:

```
class C extends A#B {
  override def fun(): Int = 100
}

trait A {
  type B = { 
    def fun(): Int 
  }
}
```

The compiler says:

```
class type required but Object{def fun(): Int} found
  class C extends A#B {
                    ^
```

How can I understand that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extend a structural type in Scala. Structural types only denote a bunch of methods which a type has to define in order to be used at places where the structural type is expected.

Thus, it is sufficient to write

```scala
class C {
  def fun(): Int = 100
}
```

to pass objects of type `C` to variables of `B`.